# Price Field Regular Expression Without Prefixed 0 for Cents

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation, expression, field

I'm using the following regular expression to validate a price field:

```
(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?$
```

It works absolutely perfectly except for when a user types in a price of the form .60, etc. If I add a 0 in front, like 0.60, it seems to work fine, but I would like to allow the user to ommit the 0 as a prefix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this syntax for **(optional_subgroup)?** i.e. nest in another pair of parentheses '(...)' and append '?'

In your case, the entire integer subpart `(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d+))` is optional. Hence

```
((\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*)|(\d+))?(\.\d{2})?$
```

However now this will match totally empty expressions, i.e. 0 integer and 0 decimal digits.
So we must require either *at least 1 integer digit (+ optional decimal part)*...

```
((\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*)|(\d+))(\.\d{2})?
```

or *at least 2 decimal digits (+ optional integer part))*...

```
((\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*)?|(\d+))(\.\d{2})
```

So match either of those two `(INTEGER)(DECIMAL)?|(INTEGER)?(DECIMAL)` - we could compress your regex if you tell us more.

Alternatively, postprocess the match (in ASP) to reject the 0 integer + 0 decimal digits case. (Can you post that ASP snippet?)

Don't match a decimal point all by itself. It's up to you whether you allow a single decimal digit: `.1`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm using asp.net and will tag it as such :)

Answer (score 1):

```
(\d{1,3}(\,\d{3})*|(\d*))(\.\d{2})?$
```